# How to declare a (global?) variable that acts as an integer or boolean value in WebMatrix C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, variables, webmatrix

all,

I was just wondering if there was a logistical way to not reassign the variable pageCount each time the page loads, yet still not get the unnasigned variable YSOD screen.

I am trying to increment pageCount each time the page is loaded, so that I can force "history.go(pageCount * -1)" (in JavaScript).

If I assign pageCount to 0 normally (e.g., int pageCount = 0;), it will reset it to 0 each time the page loads, but if I initialize it in a branch, it is out of scope for the hidden input field value plotted in C# (for JavaScript to pick up on the other side).

I have tried AppState but it doesn't like to work as an int (or bool for that matter) even if I try to cast it like:

```
(int)AppState["pageCount"];
```

Any suggestions on how I can declare a global (for lack of a better word) variable as int or bool, or perhaps apply logic to declare a regular variable that doesn't reset to its initialized value every time the page loads?

```
var username = "";
var user = "";
var password = "";
var errorMessage = "";
var loginSuccess = "not";
AppState["gActionMessage"] = "";
int pageCount;
if(!IsPost)
{
    pageCount = 1;
}
if(IsPost)
{
    pageCount++;
    username = Request.Form["username"];
    password = Request.Form["password"];

    if(username.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty())
    {
        errorMessage = "You must specify both a username and password.";
    }
    else
    {
        if (WebSecurity.UserExists(username) && WebSecurity.GetPasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess(username) > 4 && WebSecurity.GetLastPasswordFailureDate(username).AddSeconds(120) > DateTime.UtcNow) {
            AppState["gActionMessage"] = "You're account has been locked due to too many failed login attempts. " +
                                        "Please try again in 2 minutes.";
            AppState["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
            Response.Redirect("~/");
            return;
        }

        if(WebSecurity.Login(username, password, false))
        {
            var db = Database.Open("Users");
            user = (db.QuerySingle("SELECT firstName FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", username)).firstName;

            AppState["gActionMessage"] = "Hello, " + user + "!";
            AppState["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
            loginSuccess = "is";
            //Response.Redirect("~/");
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Login failed. Please check your user name and password for errors.";
            loginSuccess = "not";
        }
    }
}
```

The above code errors on the 7th line, due to pageCount being unassigned.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: AppState is for the whole website and would affect all users.  Perhaps you want Session (which is sort of like AppState ) for just the individual user?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: I think I have to change all of my AppStates to Session...... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppState` collection is a collection of `object` references. To store an `int` or `bool` value, it would be boxed.

To read it you simply unbox it, just as you tried. However, if you don't know if it's set already, you have to get it as an object reference and check if you got a reference or not. Once you have checked that you actually have a reference, you can unbox the value:

```
int pageCount;
object p = AppState["pageCount"];
if (p != null) {
  pageCount = (int)p;
} else {
  pageCount = 1; // some default value that you want to use
}
```

Comment: @VoidKing: That's what's done when you need a reference to a value type. An object is created on the heap, and the value is stored in the object. More reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: Nice answer, nice link, Thank You!

Comment: Ok, I guess I can't accept this answer, because it doesn't really solve the issue.  No matter how much boxing or unboxing I do, I still have to have a variable (that has been initialized, which sets it to 0 cause it must be assigned) because I cannot reference the AppState. I can unbox the AppState and put it in random object, but it will produce the same results.  What am I not getting?

Comment: in short I can't do this:  AppState["pageCount"]++ OR AppState["pageCount"] += 1, etc.

Comment: @VoidKing: You can't treat the `AppState` collection like a regular variable. If you want to change a value in the collection you need to read it from the collection, unbox it to get the value, change the value, and the put the value back in the collection. Get the variable as the example in the answer, then `pageCount++; AppState["pageCount"] = pageCount;`.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see, I guess after 8 hours straight yesterday, my brain was a little fried. :)